# How does cut with breaks work in R

Tags: r, split, binning

I am trying to understand how cut divides and creates intervals; tried **?cut** but can't be able to figure out how **cut** in **r** works.
Here is my problem:

```
set.seed(111)
data1 <- seq(1,10, by=1)
data1 
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
data1cut<- cut(data1, breaks = c(0,1,2,3,5,7,8,10), labels = FALSE)
data1cut
[1] 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 7
```

1. Why did 8,9,10 not included in **data1cut** result?
2. why did **summary(data1)** and **summary(data1cut)** produces different result?

```
summary(data1)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00 

summary(data1cut)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.00    3.25    4.50    4.40    5.75    7.00
```

How should i better use **cut** so that i can create say **4 bins** based on the results of **summary(data1)**?

```
bin1 [1 -3.25]
bin2 (3.25 -5.50]
bin3 (5.50 -7.75]
bin4 (7.75 -10]
```

Thank you.

Comment: why do you think some of the values are not included ? what did you expect as the `cut` result ? maybe try `cut` on values that are not the first integers to avoid confusion, and read carefully the paragraph **Value** from `?cut` : *A factor is returned, unless labels = FALSE which results in an integer vector of level codes.*

Comment: may be my understanding of `cut` is very limited. What i expect when i do a `cut` was a bin in the ranges created and corresponding values(factors) in the bins? So, assumed distribution metric results such as `summary(data1cut)`  and `summary(data1)` be similar?

Comment: What cut does is indeed put your data into bins and, for each of your vector values, it gives the "code" of the associated bins. You can do `table(data1, data1cut)` to better understand which value falls in which bin

Comment: Thank you and it is making sense now; but if we do a `boxplot(data1)` and `boxplot(data1cut)`, we get  different quartile  and median visualization. How should one go about justifying the two plots are same (assuming they mean the same thing again)?

Comment: no justification needed, they are not the same. You should use `labels=paste0("bin", 1:7)` in the `cut` call, it may make it clearer to you. By the way, there is absolutely no need for a `set.seed` call here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`cut` in your example splits the vector into the following parts:
0-1 (`1`); 1-2 (`2`); 2-3 (`3`); 3-5 (`4`); 5-7 (`5`); 7-8 (`6`); 8-10 (`7`)

The numbers in brackets are default labels assigned by `cut` to each bin, based on the `breaks` values provided.

`cut` by default is exclusive of the lower range. If you want to change that then you need to specify it in the `include.lowest` argument.

1. You did not assign labels and default argument in this function is FALSE so an integer vector of level codes (in brackets) is used instead.
2. `summary(data1)` is a summary of raw data and `summary(data1cut)` is a summary of your splits.

You can get the split you need using:

```
data2cut<- 
  cut(data1, breaks = c(1, 3.25, 5.50, 7.75, 10),
      labels = c("1-3.25", "3.25-5.50", "5.50-7.75", "7.75-10"),
      include.lowest = TRUE)
```

The result is the following:

```
> data2cut

 [1] 1-3.25    1-3.25    1-3.25    3.25-5.50 3.25-5.50 5.50-7.75 5.50-7.75 7.75-10   7.75-10  
[10] 7.75-10  
Levels: 1-3.25 3.25-5.50 5.50-7.75 7.75-10
```

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Many thanks, and all except the first line is clear. Why did the bin at 3-5 holds only value `4` and not `5`; 5-7 only `5` but not `6 , 7` (because the upper values are included by default in the bin and assumed bin 8-10 holds `9, 10`; but obviously that is not the case) the same goes for the other bins? Could you elaborate a bit how `cut` splits and returns a factor? Are there any lose of data in the process? Thanks again.

Comment: bin 3-5 holds both `4` and `5`. When you use `data1cut[5]` it will return `4` which is the fourth bin, i.e. bin3-5. Please re-read @Cath 's responses, she explained `cut` very clearly. I think you are confusing the actual values with default bin labels.