# Converting multiple columns from numeric to character in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `diary00` with multiple columns that starts with "`act1`". These columns contain numeric values.

I want to categorise these numeric values into 3 groups. Say, I want to classify 1,2,3,4 as leisure, 5,6,7 as work and 8,9,0 as home.

Is there a way for me to use either the function starts_with("act1") or "^act1" then convert the numeric values to character all at once?

I tried using the mutate() and recode() functions.

```
mutate(act1_001 = recode (act1_001, 1,2,3,4 = "leisure")
```

but an error returns:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  mutate(act1_001 = recode(act1_001, 1,2,3,4 = "leisure")
```

Comment: look into the function called `cut` or `case_when` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123458/how-does-cut-with-breaks-work-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the same transformation to multiple columns, use `across()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

diary00 <- tibble(
  act1_a = sample(0:9, 10),
  act1_b = sample(0:9, 10)
)

diary00 |> 
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("act1"),
    \(x) case_when(
      x %in% 1:4 ~ "leisure",
      x %in% 5:7 ~ "work",
      x %in% c(8, 9, 0) ~ "home"
    )
  ))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    act1_a  act1_b 
#>    <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 leisure work   
#>  2 home    leisure
#>  3 work    leisure
#>  4 leisure home   
#>  5 leisure work   
#>  6 work    leisure
#>  7 home    work   
#>  8 leisure leisure
#>  9 work    home   
#> 10 home    home
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Note input of @Onyambu:

```
library(dplyr)

diary00 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("act1"), ~cut(
    .,
    breaks = c(-1, 4, 7, 9), 
    labels = c("leisure", "work", "home"),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    right = FALSE
  )))
```

Here is a version using `cut`:

```
set.seed(123) 
diary00 <- data.frame(
  act1a = sample(0:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
  act1b = sample(0:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
  act1c = sample(0:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
  other_column = sample(0:9, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

library(dplyr)

diary00 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("act1"), ~cut(
    .,
    breaks = c(-Inf, 0.5, 4.5, 7.5, Inf), 
    labels = c("home", "leisure", "work", "home"),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  )))
```

```
    act1a   act1b   act1c other_column
1  leisure    home    home            5
2     work    work    home            4
3     home    work    home            4
4  leisure    home    work            5
5     work    home leisure            1
6  leisure    home    work            4
7     home leisure    home            6
8     home    work    home            5
9     work    home leisure            4
10 leisure    home    work            7
```

Comment: why would you use decimals? consider using `cut(1:10, c(1,4,7, 10),c("leisure", "work", "home"), include.lowest = T)`

Comment: @Onyambu. You are correct; in this case, it's better to use `cut(1:10, c(1, 4, 7, 10), c("leisure", "work", "home"), include.lowest = TRUE)` 
since all values are integers. I must admit that I regularly encounter problems using `cut` to set the correct boundaries,  especially with decimal numbers like BMI. To solidify the boundaries in my mind, I often resort to using decimals.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `dplyr::case_match()` as a roughly equivalent to `case_when` used by @dufei:

```
diary00 |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("act1"),\(x)
  case_match(x,1:4 ~ "leisure"
              ,5:7 ~ "work"
              ,c(0,8,9) ~ "home"
             )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` with `data.table`.

```
> library(data.table)
> cols <- grep('^act1_[0-9]$', names(dat), value=TRUE)
> setDT(dat)[, (paste0(cols, '_cat')) := lapply(.SD, cut, breaks=c(-1, 0, 4, 7, 9), 
+                                           labels=c('home', 'leisure', 'work', 'home')), 
+            .SDcols=cols]
> dat
    X1 X2 act1_1 act1_2 act1_1_cat act1_2_cat
 1:  X  X      0      2       home    leisure
 2:  X  X      4      8    leisure       home
 3:  X  X      0      8       home       home
 4:  X  X      8      3       home    leisure
 5:  X  X      9      4       home    leisure
 6:  X  X      3      4    leisure    leisure
 7:  X  X      1      3    leisure    leisure
 8:  X  X      9      1       home    leisure
 9:  X  X      0      7       home       work
10:  X  X      7      2       work    leisure
11:  X  X      6      9       work       home
12:  X  X      3      0    leisure       home
13:  X  X      8      9       home       home
14:  X  X      4      7    leisure       work
15:  X  X      3      5    leisure       work
16:  X  X      9      9       home       home
17:  X  X      1      7    leisure       work
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(X1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), X2 = c("X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X"), act1_1 = c(0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 1L), act1_2 = c(2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```